# Python. Задача с Codewars

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть задача https://www.codewars.com/kata/556deca17c58da83c00002db/python

Вкратце, каждый следующий элемент последовательности являет сумму трех предыдущих. Среди входных данных есть число N, передающее сколько элементов последовательности надо вернуть (последовательность возможно надо сократить).

И есть рабочее решение:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    return [ signature.append(sum(signature)) or signature.pop(0) for i in range(n) ]
```

Вопросов у меня три:

Как sum понимает что нужно суммировать не все элементы списка а только последние 3?

Почему pop(0) удаляя первый элемент списка, дает правильное решение? По логике, при наличии списка длинной больше N, нужно удалять последние элементы.

Как or вообще что-то тут делает что оно все работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что происходит следующее

1. добавляется новый элемент равный сумме всех элементов через `signature.append`
2. удаляется первый элемент из списка через `signature.pop(0)`

поскольку `signature.append` не возвращает значение (возвращает `None`), то обязательно будет выполнено `signature.pop(0)`

а поскольку в качестве параметра передается список из трех элементов, то каждый шаг добавляется 1 элемент, удаляется 1 элемент итого остается ровно 3 элемента

P.S.
но решение оригинальное, интересное :)

P.P.S.
можно использовать и такое решение:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
  for i in range(n):
    signature.append(sum(signature[-3:]))

  return signature[:n]
```

тут явно видно